# multi selection

Tags: delphi, selection

I’m trying to give the user selection group of 8 checkboxes (CheckBox1, CheckBox2, …etc), where the user can chose any combination from the eight check boxes.  For each selection there will be different coding
For example

```
If CheckBox1.checked then
Begin
End
Else
If CheckBox1.checked  and CheckBox2 .checked  then
Begin

End 
Else
If….
```

Please give any idea on how to do it ,  other than going through the If – else statements which are very nested in my case and I’m getting so confused
thank you

**Update**

Ok, let me clarify more. I’m building in the HR system- renewal contract process , the user can choose to renew employee’s contract only, or to renew it and give annual bonus, or to change the job-title with renewal, or give extra bonus with the annual raise… that is the logic and I have no idea what is the best way to implement it.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify more. 
I’m building in the HR system- renewal contract process ,  the user can choose to renew employee’s contract only, or to renew it and give annual bonus, or  to change the job-title with renewal, or give extra bonus with the annual raise… that is the logic and I have no idea what is the best way to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate the logic into multiple Groups.  On the primary GroupBox, have just the Renew CheckBox by itself (and whatever other non-Renew options you need).  Then have a second GroupBox that has options for Give Annual Bonus, Change Job Title, and Give Extra Bonus with Raise.  When the Renew CheckBox is checked, show the second GroupBox.  When the Renew CheckBox is unchecked, hide the second GroupBox.  That will present fewer options to the user, and makes sure that the user can only pick combinations that are valid for your requirements.

Comment: Group box with just a single checkbox is rather pointless. It would be more natural to have the renew/not renew checkbox not contained in a group box. The additional options which are available when renewed would be good in a group box. That group box could be either hidden when not renewed, or shown but disabled with all options unchecked.  I personally would prefer the latter but arguments can be made both ways.

Comment: @Amamda Remy here is specialising my general advice to your specific case. When you have only two mutually exclusive options then that can be presented either as a single check box or as two radio buttons. There's no single clear cut better choice. With two radio buttons you don't need to force the user to handle negatives. You can offer them the following choice: - Renew - Don't renew. You have to choose whichever approach is more appropriate. Of course if you had a 3rd mutually exclusive choice, say Transfer, then you would be compelled to use radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

A group of check boxes are typically used when the options are independent of each other. That means your logic is generally not nested. It would look something like this:

```
if checkbox1.Checked then
  ....
else
  ....;

if checkbox2.Checked then
  ....
else
  ....;
```

and so on.

If there are strong interactions between the meaning of your check boxes then that would complicate matters. It's rather hard to advise you without known more details of your specific problem. However, good solutions to problems like this typically involve finding ways to remove the inter-dependencies in the code and making it possible to use independent logic as above.

---

Your updated question gives more information. You say:

> the user can choose to renew employee’s contract only, or to renew it and give annual bonus, or to change the job-title with renewal, or give extra bonus with the annual raise

This sounds like a mutually exclusive list of options. In which case a group of check boxes is the wrong UI element. You should use a radio group, [`TRadioGroup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TRadioGroup). This is a group of radio buttons of which *only one* can be selected. This can then be mapped onto, say, an enumerated type and your logic can become a simple case statement.

If you implement this UI using check boxes then it will be possible for the user to select a combination of options that is not possible. For example they may select the option to give the employee a raise but not check the option to renew the contract!

Of course some of your options may be mutually exclusive and some may be independent of each other. In that case you would need to use a combination of a radio group and some check boxes.

Comment: Radio buttons are the component of choice for mutually exclusive options. Check boxes are of service when all the options are possible, with or without dependencies.

Comment: @David. there are more options(I've listed examples) than what I mentioned, but I'll try to change the logic in order to use RadioGroup. I'll let u know what happen. thank you for your help

Comment: I can't be sure whether or not radio buttons or check boxes or some combination are the answer, but I've tried to outline the factors that lead you to make the right decision.

Comment: I'm trying to change the logic and use both groub of RadioButtons and checkboxes. I guess there isn't any easier way but this. thank you all for the ideas